# Are my home canned dill pickles safe to eat?

Tags: canning, safety, pickles

I followed the instructions from my canning book in making the pickles approximately a year ago. I opened them today and could pull the lid off with my fingers. They had seal marks in the rubber lining of the lid, but I should have needed a bottle opener to get them off. There is no obvious signs of spoilage or mold. Do dill pickles with a high vinegar content have to be hot water processed?
Addendum: I hot water bathed the quart jars for 20". The jars sat undisturbed for 24hrs. All jars sealed, meaning the lids had depressed centers. When I went to open them, the centers were still depressed. It just concerned me that I did not need a bottle opener to pop the lids off. The jars were stored in a rack in a spare room at room temperature.

Comment: Welcome Erin, we need more information to give good answers. How did you process your jar(s) and where were they stored?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I can open sealed lids with my fingers, no opener required. The important question is whether the lid (assuming standard safety lid that does this) was down, and **popped up** in the center when opened, or was already popped up before you opened it. The former is good, the latter is "discard contents carefully.."

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I edited my entry to best answer these questions.

Answer (score 1):

`When I went to open them, the centers were still depressed.`

Then they were still sealed, and should be safe to eat.